# django prepending %2F to url tag

Tags: django, django-templates

django 1.6, python 2.7
I have this url

```
url(r'^index/$', 'baseball.views.home', name='home'),
```

and this template:

```
href="{% url "home" %}">Baseball Statistics</a></h1>
```

I get this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/%2Findex/
```

I've tried |safe on the url tag, but no difference.  The link works, but it looks weird.  How can I correct this?

Comment: What happens if you replace `"{% url "home" %}"` with `"{% url 'home' %}"`?

Comment: no change.  I actually did that before, but I just now rechecked

Comment: Are there other urls in the project, and do they work properly?  Since that's being prepended **before** the `index/`, it seems likely that's a problem with the server url.  Are you maybe adding an extra '/' when you call `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: I should add that part of my suspicion comes from the fact that `%2F` is Unicode for `/`.

Comment: I'm just starting this project.  It's the first use of url tag.  I know that %2F is an escaped substitute for /.  I had a url like this: #url(r'^/', include('baseball.urls')),
and this: url(r'^stats/', include('baseball.urls')),
 I removed the first and now it works.  Thanks

Comment: Ah, got it.  For future reference, to include urls within the root url, you can use this: `url(r'^$',include('baseball.urls'))` -- that way the extra '/' won't filter down.

Comment: @MBrizzle that should be `url(r'^',include('baseball.urls'))` -- using a `$` in a regex is a different mistake when including urls ;)

Comment: Oof, yes, thank you for the catch.  Wish I could edit my comment so other people don't get caught with that mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem but due to the fact that I added a slash as highlighted below:

```
url(r'^/index/$', 'baseball.views.home', name='home')
```

Deleting the slash at the beginning solves the problem:

```
url(r'^index/$', 'baseball.views.home', name='home')
```